# Form #states visible for numeric values

Tags: 7, forms

The form has two radio buttons like follows.The "design" radio field should be visible only when user selects 'Ten' or 'hundred' from the "price" field.

If user choose 'other' it should not be visible.

I tried like follows, it's working but by default the 'design' field is come with visible state.

```
//$options array is dynamic.  
$options =  array(10 => 'Ten', 100 => 'hundred', 'other' => 'Other');

  $form['price'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Price?'),
    '#options' => $options,
    );
  $form['design'] = array(
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#title' => t('Designs'),
    '#options' => $designs,
   );
  $form['design']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
        array(':input[name="price"]' => array('!value' => 'other')),
    ),
  );
```

I've tried several ways like follows with no luck.

```
array(':input[name="price"]' => array('!value' => '')),
array(':input[name="price"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
```

Is there any option like to check the selected value is numeric or not? like

```
array(':input[name="price"]' => array('value' => isNumeric)),
```

or the other option would loop through the dynamic option values?

```
      array(':input[name="category"]' => array('value' => 10)),
      'or',
      array(':input[name="category"]' => array('value' => 100)),
      'or',
        .
        .
        etc
```

Any suggestions or input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up the issue as follows.

```
$options =  array(10 => 'Ten', 100 => 'hundred', 'other' => 'Other'); // Dynamic array
$conditions = array();
  foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
      $conditions[] = array(':input[name="price"]' => array('value' => $key));
    }
  }

  $form['design']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => $conditions,
  );
```

Hope this helps someone. Any better answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$form['design']['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="price"]' => array('!value' => 'other'),
  ),
);
```

though, to be honest I'm much more a fan of:

```
$form['design']['#states'] = array(
  'invisible' => array(
    ':input[name="price"]' => array('value' => 'other'),
  ),
);
```

[Here are some good examples](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/160344/63043) to follow. Not exactly your case, but close.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as mentioned in my question, I've already tried that, If we use this, the default state of the `design` field would always be visible until I select one of the option from `price`.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet code:**

```
      $form['design']['#states'] = array(
        'visible' => array(
           array(':input[name="price"]' => array(
              'checked' => true,
              '!value' => 'other',
            )
          ),
        ),
      );
```

**This above solution make sure 'Design' field 'll display only if:**

- User select value from 'Price' field
- Value selected from price field is not 'other'.